# Symfony assetic - is possible in dev load original files?

Tags: twig, symfony, minify, assetic, uglifyjs2

I have project on Symfony 3 with installed [assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic). I am using it for merging all css together and minify.

Usage in twig template:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' filter='uglifycss'
    'assets/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css'
    ...
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Config:

```
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs"
    uglifycss:
        bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss"
```

In prod mode all works as expected. Assetic loads css files from path `/assets/someDir/some.css` and generated minified file (css or js) is in default assetic path `/css/allCss.css` or `/js/allJs.css`.

But in develop mode assetic generate new files from `/assets/someDir/some.css` to `/css/some.css` (each file and not minified) and load css files from there.

**QUESTION:**

How i can load original files from `/assets/someDir/some.css` in dev mode?

Because in this situation i must after each change in any css or js run `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev` and it is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to run `php bin/console assetic:dump` each time you change a CSS or a JS file, use `php bin/console assetic:watch` instead, it will automatically regenerate the files on every change of CSS or JS.

Comment: One more question: If i make change in one js file `assetic:watch` processing ALL js files. Is way to process only changed file?

Comment: I don't think so. I also don't really see the point, it's quite quick.